# Feasibility of a polynomial system of equalities and inequalities

Tags: polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, semidefinite-programming, semialgebraic-geometry

Consider a system of the form $f_i(x) = 0$ and $g_j(x) \ge 0$ ,where $f_i,i=1,\dots,r$ and $g_j,j=1,\dots,s$ are polynomials in real unknowns $x_i,i=1,\dots,n$ with rational coefficients.

Is there a polynomial in the coefficients of $f_i$ and $g_j$ whose vanishing guarantees that there is no $x$ for which the system is true?

---

Edit: The comments contain the answer: thanks to the Tarski–Seidenberg theorem there is a system of polynomial inequalities in the coefficients, for each choice of coefficients which satisfy this system there is an $x$ that satisfy the original system.

Comment: This follows from the Tarski-Seidenberg theory on quantifier elimination over the reals (more generally, over real-closed fields). However, I don't know how to do this algorithmically (though the answer is probably somewhere in the book “Algorithms in Real Algebraic Geometry” by Basu, Pollack and Roy).

Comment: Thanks! I should update my question accordingly

Comment: Quantifier elimination does not give a polynomial whose vanishing expresses the given condition, but only a *Boolean combination* of polynomial *inequalities*. The wording “guarantees” is vague (is it an implication or an equivalence?) , but I don’t think the conclusion holds in any useful way. Consider the simple case of systems $\{x=0,x+a\ge0\}$ with a coefficient $a$: this has no solution if and only if $a<0$. There is no polynomial $h(a)$ that vanishes for infinitely many $a<0$, but does not vanish for $a\ge0$.

Comment: How is this related to SDP?

Comment: Thanks to the PositivStellenSatz one can turn it into an SPD, as explained e.g. in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~deloera/researchsummary/computpoly.pdf

Comment: Please provide the (full) reference to de Loera's paper in the question itself.